# How to import fbx into XNA?

Tags: xna, fbx

I am developing basic XNA car game. I used 3D fbx car models to represent car objects. I drag and drop all tga and fbx files into content and I succesfully showed car in my game by using some basic codes. But the problem is when I move the car around the components move around irrelevant because some components of fbx model have different X, Y, Z directions according to world. I tried a lot of fbx models but all of it same. Also the colors have not shown on game. What is the solution of this broblem. How can I equal all component axes to game world axes to move around together? Why I can not see the colors of components?
[image]

[image]

Comment: Seems like you need to look at your asset creation step, not the import step. The title of your question is misleading, since apparently you already know how to import them.

Comment: Maybe I am not importing it correctly. But you can edit question if you want.